# ContentDialog should not be in focus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button. When the button is pressed a ContentDialog pops up. The Background behind the ContentDialog changes its Color from it's current color to a bit into Grey. I cannot do any Actions outside the ContentDialog. The ContentDiaolog gets the full Focus.

Here is the Scenario I want to achieve.

I load a text into my program.

I click on the Button to open the ContentDialog. While the ContentDialog is in front I want to be able to do Actions on the text (Scrolling the text up/down for example). Also the text should Keep its normal Colors like as if the ContentDialog isn't open. Is this possible?

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="ContentBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Click="ContentBtn_Click">
    <ContentDialog x:Name="ContentDialog" Title="This is an example" PrimaryButtonText="Ok"></ContentDialog>        
</Button>
```

CS:

```
private async void ContentBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ContentDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with a ContentDialog.

From the documentation:

> Dialogs are modal UI overlays that provide contextual app information.
>   Dialogs **block interactions with the app window until being explicitly
>   dismissed**. They often request some kind of action from the user. [[source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/)